# Animation on each element

Tags: jquery, html, css, colors

```
$(".skills span").hover( function(){
$(".skillsIknow").stop().animate({ opacity: '1' },300);
},function(){
$(".skillsIknow").stop().animate({ opacity: '0' },300);
});
```

I have this simple animation : when you pass your mouse on the "softwares", the text "I KNOW" appears above.
But when you move your mouse between Indesign and Illustrator for exemple, the text I KNOW stays white : does it possible to create an little effect, when you change between a word, it disappears and appears ?
Thks

**PS : Does someone know why the animation color white/black doesn't work ?**

- http://jsfiddle.net/Vz6z6/

Comment: `color` cannot be animated, unless you use some plugin like [jquery color](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/24/jquery-color-2-1-0/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to fade back out, you need to force it to, otherwise it stays in the hover state. Try:

```
$(".skillsIknow").stop().animate({ opacity: '1' },300).animate({ opacity: '0' },300);
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Diodeus, you will have to force jQuery to fade it. Like this..

```
$(".skills span").hover(function () {
    $(".skillsIknow").stop().animate({
        opacity: '1'
    }, 300).animate({
        opacity: '0'
    }, 300);

}, function () {
    $(".skillsIknow").stop().animate({
        opacity: '0'
    }, 300).dequeue();
});
```

Notice, `dequeue()` is used to avoid the unnecessary blinking.

As far as changing color on hover is concerned, there are two ways to do it -

- via CSS `:hover` [read more](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)
- using jQuery plugin like [jquery color](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/24/jquery-color-2-1-0/)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vz6z6/2/) (edited your jsFiddle)

*NOTE* I've included the jquery.color.js in the `External Resources` section in the jsFiddle.